# Handlebars access an [object object]?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

So inside a model I have a structure like this. Below is a sample of the structure.

```
var myModel {
    _id: 798698,
    username: "John",
    message: {
        message1: "Some cool messsage",
        message2: "I'm mad Ohio State lost"
    }
}
```

I am using backbone marionette and handlebars of course, I have a collection view which at first was just a collection of the models.

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

var ChatView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: require('../../templates/message.hbs')
});

module.exports = CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
    },
    itemView: ChatView
});
```

Then in the `/message.hbs` the template is basic like this.

```
<div class="message"><b>{{username}}:</b>{{message}}</div>
```

Well if you look at the structure above `message` is obviously an `[object object]`.

So to the question which I am sure is easy and obvious, how do I loop this view for each object inside the `message:` attribute, so that the template itself is looped. I think I worded that right.

See ideally It would be nice to create a collection within the model, but I didn't know how and the objects inside `message:` are built in a vanilla way.

So that said I am hoping there is a way to loop those objects with backbone/backbone.marionette and handlebars.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, use #each:

```
<div class="message">
    <b>{{username}}:</b>
    {{#each message}}
        <div>{{this}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, believe it or not I did read the docs, but I did so very lazily. Thanks for pointing that out...